# How to get images to planes objects to receive shadow?

Tags: node-editor

I'm following this tutorial where you create a popular illusion using images as planes.

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sk87jDzHGKA

However, I can't seem to get the object to receive shadow unlike other objects I've worked with before. It could be that the nodes I've used to get this result is a mix shader that uses the images of the back and front of the illusion with backfacing but I don't know how to get around this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please share your file (also pack external images to have all the assets). It's not clear if you have any light or not. without lights there are no shadows.

Comment: There is a light. It's just that the images to planes has no shadows. Do you know how to attach a .blend file to this post?

Comment: Well, "images to plane" have so many problems, why don't start from a standard plane? The process is the same (I know the tutorial use "images to plane" but there is no reason to follow this part). Otherwise you can try to use a solidify modifier to have a 3d mesh from a plane and so cast shadows.

Comment: Alright I'll try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some looking around, I found the solution. Since I was using only image textures and a mix shader no shadows would be created. I had to put the images through a principled bsdf node before giving it to the mix shader so shadows could be created.

[image]